# ol-ext: control legend with image item - how to decrease space between items?

Tags: openlayers, legend, css, ol-ext

I'm using the example http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/legend/map.control.legend.image.html with OpenLayers to show the legend of my layers.

However, I would like to decrease the space between the items, for example: Triangle, Square, etc,
and I don't know where in the CSS I make this change. How can I do this?

[image]

[CODE]

```
 // New legend associated with a layer
 var stamenLegend = new ol.legend.Legend({ layer: stamen, margin: 4 })
 stamenLegend.addItem({ title: 'Form' })
 var form = { Triangle:3, Square:4, Pentagon: 5, Hexagon: 6 };
 for (var i in form) {
   stamenLegend.addItem({ 
    title: i, 
    typeGeom: 'Point',
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
        points: form[i],
        radius: 15,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: [255,128,0,1 ], width: 1.5 
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: [255,255,0,.3 ]})
    })
  })
});
```

}

legend.addItem(stamenLegend)

Comment: You can trying setting margin and/or the vertical component of size to less than their default values, see https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.legend.Legend.html

Comment: @Mike Thank you, decrease the margin and it improved a little.